# One-to-one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, associations

I have two models and I want to display them in one table.

Model 1:

```
class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :employer, :foreign_key => 'application_id'
end
```

Model 2:

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :name, :foreign_key => 'application_id'
end
```

Controller:

```
def summary
    @name = Name.all
end
```

I have this in my view:

```
<% @name.each do |e| %>
 <tr>
   <td ><%= e.application_id %></td>
   <td ><%= e.Name_of_employee%></td>
   <td ><%= e.Employer_name%></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

The name only have one employer. 
I am getting "undefined method `Employer' for #
"

TYIA!

Comment: What are the attributes in `names` and `employers` table? You have to display attributes/association names not *Classname*

Comment: Also is your `foreign_key` is `application-id` or `application_id`?

Comment: it's application_id, just a typo. I'll edit. thanks!

Comment: Don't change the original question!

Answer (score 3):

as the association is defined,

```
has_one :employer, :foreign_key => 'application-id'
```

notice the case `employer`, so it has to be small case, and not class name

```
<td ><%= e.employer.name %></td> # name or some other attribute you wish to display
```

Also, including the association first will help eliminate `n+1`

```
@name = Name.includes(:employer)
```